# No response while joining conference SmackException NoResponseException

Tags: xmpp, chat, smack, asmack

i am getting below exception while joining the conference chat.

Exception:

> org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response
>   received within reply timeout. Timeout was 10000ms (~10s). Waited for
>   response using: AndFilter: (StanzaTypeFilter: Presence, OrFilter:
>   (AndFilter: (FromMatchesFilter (ignoreResourcepart):
>   hdhd@conference.35.171.18.126, MUCUserStatusCodeFilter: status=110),
>   AndFilter: (FromMatchesFilter (full):
>   hdhd@conference.35.171.18.126/user00000003, StanzaIdFilter:
>   id=c3v5j-70, PresenceTypeFilter: type=error))). 07-02 12:39:58.019
>   31567-31567/com.br.granplay W/System.err:     at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.StanzaCollector.nextResultOrThrow(StanzaCollector.java:260)

Code:

```
muc = MucManager.getInstance()
                        .getMultiUserChat(MucManager.getEntityBareJid(jid));
                String strresource = XmppConnection.getXMPPConnction()
                        .getUser().getLocalpart().toString();
                Resourcepart resourcepart = Resourcepart.from(strresource);
                MucEnterConfiguration.Builder mec = muc.getEnterConfigurationBuilder(
                       resourcepart);

                mec.requestNoHistory();
                MucEnterConfiguration mucEnterConfig = mec.build();
                muc.join(mucEnterConfig);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using below config for the xmpp connection before fix.

```
 XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration conf = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setXmppDomain(mServiceName)
                .setHostAddress(getIpAddressOrNull(mServiceName))
                .setResource("Android")
                .setUsernameAndPassword(mUsername, mPassword) 
                .setKeystoreType(null) //This line seems to get rid of the problem
                .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                .setCompressionEnabled(true)
                .setSendPresence(true)
                .setDebuggerEnabled(false)
                .build();
```

Problem Fixed after removing resource part.

```
.setResource("Android")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout
```

Generally, this exception comes when user's presence is not updated to the Openfire server and try to join a room.

So update your presence(Unavailable) on onStop(), on close app.
And set your presence(Available) onResume().

Still, you get this exception then on exception send user's presence "Unavailable" to the Openfire server and after 1-2 sec sends presence "Available" and then join to group.